# Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common when create custom component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to create a custom button for my app to use later, it look like this

```
const BUTTON_SHAPE: ViewStyle = {
  borderRadius: 30,
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
};
export interface AppButtonProps {
  style?: ViewStyle;
  child?: Element | React.ReactNode;
}
const AppButton = (props: AppButtonProps) => {
  const {style, child} = props;
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[style, BUTTON_SHAPE]}>{child}</TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
export default AppButton;
```

But. when i use this in App:

```
 <ViewContainer style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <AppButton>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
      </AppButton>
      <AppText>Login</AppText>
    </ViewContainer>
```

It show error:

```
Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & AppButtonProps'
```

[image]

How can i fix this, what did i do wrong? Please help, thank you a lots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass children elements in React, you should use the special `children` property.

simply upadate your `AppButton` `child` prop to `children`

```js
const BUTTON_SHAPE: ViewStyle = {
  borderRadius: 30,
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
};
export interface AppButtonProps {
  style?: ViewStyle;
  children?: Element | React.ReactNode;
}
const AppButton = (props: AppButtonProps) => {
  const {style, children} = props;
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[style, BUTTON_SHAPE]}>{children}</TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Comment: It works! I just thought it just a prop then i can give anyname, thank for your answer

Comment: `children` is more of a default one. you can see this in action if you try to print out the virtual dom setup.